# Вывод нескольких innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Как правильно выводить несколько дивов за раз с помощью **innerHTML**?

```js
var my_div = newDiv = null;

function addElement() {

  // Создаём новый элемент div
  // и добавляем в него немного контента

  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.innerHTML = "<h1>Привет!</h1>";
  newDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>Пока!</h2>";

  // Добавляем только что созданный элемент в дерево DOM

  my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='org_div1' onclick="addElement();">Текст выше сгенерирован автоматически.</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: если у тебя появился новый вопрос - задай его отдельно

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```js
var my_div = newDiv = null;

function addElement() {

  // Создаём новый элемент div
  // и добавляем в него немного контента

  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.innerHTML += "<h1>Привет!</h1>";
  newDiv.innerHTML += "<h2>Пока!</h2>";

  // Добавляем только что созданный элемент в дерево DOM

  my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
}
```

```css
#org_div1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id='org_div1' onclick="addElement();">Текст выше сгенерирован автоматически.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как правильно выводить несколько дивов за раз с помощью innerHTML?

Например вот таким образом добавлять.

```js
var my_div = newDiv = null;

function addElement() {

  // Создаём новый элемент div
  // и добавляем в него немного контента

  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.innerHTML = "<h1>Привет!</h1>";
  newDiv.innerHTML += "<h2>Пока!</h2>";

  // Добавляем только что созданный элемент в дерево DOM

  my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='org_div1' onclick="addElement();">Текст выше сгенерирован автоматически.</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
    at addElement (index.html?:347:19)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (index.html?:237:44)

Как решить такую ошибку?

Comment: Я понял что типо из-за того что сверху уже имеются другие блоки не дает, а как сделать так что бы давало?

Comment: Для ответа желательно посмотреть что ты там делаешь.

Comment: Для работы с html-текстом удобнее использовать `insertAdjacentHTML`. https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document#insertadjacenthtml-text-element

Comment: щас дам ниже код который делаю посмотри и дай под него комментарий

Answer (score -1):

Ну или так:

```js
var my_div = newDiv = null;

function addElement() {

  // Создаём новый элемент div
  // и добавляем в него немного контента

  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.innerHTML +=
  "<h1>Привет!</h1>"
  + "<h2>Пока!</h2>";

  // Добавляем только что созданный элемент в дерево DOM

  my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
}
```

```css
#org_div1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id='org_div1' onclick="addElement();">Текст выше сгенерирован автоматически.</div>
```